# Snooping on iOS API calls?

Tags: ios, debugging, snoop

I'd like to see what kinds of API/framework calls are being made by an arbitrary iOS app. Is there some sort of mechanism or tool that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, the term you are looking for is [hooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking).  It can be easily be done on a [Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking#Windows) system.

Excerpt from Wikipedia:
[ptrace](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man2/ptrace.2.html) is a system call found in several Unix and Unix-like operating systems.

Given the design of iOS running one app at a time, I don't believe you can do this. Plus your app will be running in a sandbox environment with each app having it's own virtual address space.